# WP Query to select posts at random the display in numerical order

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am using query_posts to return 6 ramdom posts from a custom post type using orderby=rand.

This works fine. However. Once the query has returned the posts I need them to be sorted in numerical order.

the current code I am using looks like this:

```
<?php query_posts('post_type=my_post_type&orderby=rand&showposts=6'); ?>
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

Do stuff

<?php endwhile; else: ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

So I need 6 posts to be selected at random then they need to be sorted in to numerical order. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I feel it worth making clear that ORDER BY RAND can be VERY inefficient.  Not likely an issue if this is a small table but potentially one in the long run.  Additionally can't really advise without knowing what is within the function query_posts.

Comment: Hi Simon, it's only a small table with 49 posts. Each post's title is a number from 1 - 49. We need it to select 6 of the posts at random, then show them in numerical order by post title

Comment: I'm assuming this is a wordpress function in which case http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts doesn't indicate a way to simply achieve what you are aiming to

Comment: Ok, so do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Some meta-code for you, actually getting this working will require some digging on your part but this will hopefully get on on the right track.

The general idea here is that you just need to get the ids from the query_posts and then reorder them, allowing you to output them as you desire.

```
<?php 
    query_posts('post_type=my_post_type&orderby=rand&showposts=6'); 

    // Create your result array
    $postArray = array();

    if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

        $postArray[] = /*POST ID GOES HERE*/

    endwhile; else:
    endif;

    // Now sort it
    sort($postArray,SORT_NUMERIC);

    // Now iterate over $postArray outputting post id $postArray[0] -> $postArray[n]

?>
```

Another option could be to populate $postArray with `$postArray[/*POST ID*/] = /* OUTPUT */;` and then just iterate over $postArray as PHP probably *should* automatically sort it if numeric keys are used.